# Sometime My SQL query returns empty result

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I have developed asp.net application using **MySql** database.

The website was developed using `.net framework 3.5`. We have used `.Net 2.0 ODBC driver`. We found that sometimes we execute the query ,returns empty result set. But when we execute the same query using **Mysql** editor , it  returns data.

Example:
`SELECT * FROM tblUsers WHERE user_name='Crystal'`

My connection config:

```
 <connectionStrings>
        <clear />
        <add name="CmsDb" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="Datasource=ball.Domain.com;Database=sampledatabase;uid=dbadmin;pwd=admin123;Port=3306;Pooling=True;" />
      </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: can you post the code, in asp.net with the sql query? Is 'Crystal' value is predefined or from a input field?

Comment: Actually the issue is not because of mysql query.We have debugged the code and executed the query  in mysql query browser returns data

Comment: But have tried to debug your query on .NET?

Comment: Yes we have debug the query in visual studio and copied the query  that is  returning empty result , then the same query is executed in Mysql editor.It returns records successfully.